# MySQL PDO Name-Value Prepared Statement Using Last Parameter Only

Tags: php, pdo, mysqli

As titled, I'm using MySQL PDO with a prepared statement, and when executing, I'm getting a single value (the last supplied value) pushed into all fields.

Table looks like so:

- id (int - auto-increment)
- a_id (int)
- b_id (int)

INSERT looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(a_id, b_id) 
VALUES (:a_id, :b_id)
```

Code to insert looks like this...

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

foreach($params as $k => $v) {
    $stmt->bindParam(
        $k,
        $v
    );
}

$stmt->execute();
```

The statement successfully inserts a value (which confirms $conn is present, active and open and the statement is set up and parameters bound).

I have confirmed the values by debugging inside the **foreach**, where I get two parameters (in $params) of ":a_id" => 1, ":b_id" => 9999...

**My record goes in as ({new_id}, 9999, 9999) though.***

This means it sees and uses ":b_id" => 9999, but appears to drop or overwrite ":a_id" => 1...

I thought maybe the underscore was a problem (but apparently several people have reviewed source in the past to indicate underscore is fine... though hyphen is not).

I'm not reusing parameters (my understanding is one use allowed per prepared statement)...

Is there some named parameter issue I'm missing here? Since it's basically ->bindParam() to ->execute(), there's not a lot of room for me troubleshoot.

I'm trying to address speed issues with ORM-based data access while using the Fat Free Framework, but I can't think that there's interference there.

*For reference, this is running under PHP 5.5.8 / Windows / IIS.*

**EDIT:***

I can confirm that moving to positional parameters is doing the same thing.

```
INSERT INTO my_table(a_id, b_id) 
VALUES (?, ?)
```

Code changed to...

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$i = 1;
foreach($params as $value) {
    $stmt->bindParam(
        $i,
        $value
    );
    $i++;
}

$stmt->execute();
```

To clarify how the $params array is being set... things are being passed through to this code (which is the heart of an abstract db handler), and the array is manually constructed...

i.e.

```
$results = \XX\DB::do_cmd(
    $db, 
    self::SQL_INSERT, 
    array(
        ':a_id' => intval($this->a_id),
        ':b_id' => intval($this->b_id),
    )
);
```

Still got ({new_id}, 9999, 9999)...

NOTE: To remove confusion, in addition to going to a positional based pass, I also hardcoded values to see what I'd get...

```
$results = \XX\DB::do_cmd(
    $db, 
    self::SQL_INSERT, 
    array(
        1,
        1234,
    )
);
```

My record came out ({new_id}, 1234, 1234). Same problem, differing values.

I have the feeling there's a "gotcha" here... but I have no idea what it is.

The interesting thing, is that I double check the table for an existing record before the INSERT based on those two values (to prevent duplication) and the check correctly identifies that the record is there... despite it being wrong in the database... which means SELECT and INSERT are doing the same thing with the parameters (though not all that surprising, since parameter handling is the same).

EDIT2:

Update to note as solved. Using...

```
$stmt->execute($params); // scrap the foreach nonsense...
```

bindValue() rather than bindParam() is also appropriate.

NOTE: I was working from the following PHP documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) which doesn't differentiate bindValue() vs bindParam()...

Comment: Can you post the code which sets `$params` and the code which defines `$sql`?  It _is_ possible to reuse params if PDO is emulating prepares (`ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`), which is the _default_ for MySQL.

Comment: Also please post `var_dump($params)` though you have debugged it already.  You can simplify this to avoid `bindParam()` because you aren't specifying types.  You could just be using `$stmt->execute($params)`

Comment: Use 'bindValue' rather than 'bindParam' in your 'foreach' loop. Otherwise you are only binding to the variable '$v' of which there is only one! and the last value it has is '9999'.

Comment: @RyanVincent Well spotted.

Comment: I can confirm both options as noted by RyanVincent and @MichaelBerkowski work (i.e. executing directly on $params and using bindValue rather than BindParam). Thanks! I'm not sure about how to mark an answer here, but I'm pretty sure somebody has to post one outside a comment...

Comment: Pinging @RyanVincent to let him know his solution works too.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question - you can accept your own answer. It will provide others with how you felt with us - 'assisting' :-) Was fun for us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all the help everybody!

I went with Michael's solution, but tested Ryan's too.

i.e.

Update to note as solved. Using...

```
$stmt->execute($params); // scrap the foreach nonsense...
```

bindValue() rather than bindParam() is also appropriate.

To wrap things up, as per Ryan's comment, I'm pushing an answer out.

Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer with credits for us - we are all glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

The variable has to be call-by-reference:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

foreach($params as $k => &$v) {
    $stmt->bindParam(
        $k,
        $v
    );
}
$stmt->execute();
```

See the first user-contributed comment here:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: That wouldn't work... It would execute with each parameter... If I were doing multiple INSERTs, I might ->execute() inside that loop. ... Turns out, the loop is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Sorry - I mis-read the question the first time and jumped to conclusions. I re-read and totally changed my answer.

Comment: That's a different answer than originally proposed, but you're right, (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#98145) does bring attention to the variable being passed by reference; however, I shouldn't have to enforce that and I'm not sure what that will do in the foreach. I only know for certain that the & can't go in the function call (5.3.0 generates a warning, 5.4.0 a fatal error, etc.): http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: You did see that the & goes in the foreach part of the loop rather than in the call to the function, right?  Basically my answer was the same as Ryan's - he's pointing out that you are binding it to the single variable $v and I'm explaining how to get past that problem.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I get it what you were going after now. I think I've seen it more commonly expressed via "dummy" variables ... (i.e. my_func($k, $dummy = $v); type thing...) especially in actual function calls, but you're grabbing the reference to the variable as opposed to the variable in this case to correct the binding issue. If I'm still thick and you're willing to go further, feel free, but I think we're basically covered.